# Export angular component with same path to another module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components, angular-router

I have got next problem. Two modules: AuthorModule and BookModule. They have got 2 different components AuthorListComponent and BookListComponent, but the same path in modules. When I want to include in AuthorListComponent BookListComponent. BookListComponent rewrite all logic in AuthorListComponent and show only its data.

app.routing.ts:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'book',
        loadChildren: () => import('./book/book.module').then(m => m.BookModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'author',
        loadChildren: () => import('./author/author.module').then(m => m.AuthorModule)
    }
   ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

book.routing.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: BookListComponent,
        resolve: { model: BookResolver }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

author.routing.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AuthorListComponent,
        resolve: { model: AuthorResolver }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

author.list.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let author of authors" >
 <div>{{author.name}}</div>
   <book-list-component [authorId]="author.id"></<book-list-component>
</div>
```

book.list.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let book of books" >
  <div>{{book.name}}</div>
  <div>{{book.year}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrong children reference. Use it like this: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-basics

Comment: @Numichi example please

Comment: There is under link. You can read this.

Comment: @Numichi changed, but it doesnt help

Comment: I know. :) But it's so hard to know what's in the component. We are still blind. You specified a routing and html. Example: You use "model" to resolve and you are using "books" and "authors" variable. We dont know how change or how work data flow, what did you call url, what was output and what is expected. We won't figure it out. The question is incomplete. Therefore, no substantive answer was received too. Because there's nothing to answer for.

Comment: I found the solution. Use <router-outlet></router-outler>